# how to make picture move without stopping in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, move

I am making game, in which I have "Orange" "Witch" "MyGame" classes. Oranges just draw on the screen, and whitches go from some position on the screen to the position of the oranges. user kills witches by clicking on them, and when amount of alive witches == 2 for example, a few new witches should appear in the old(first) position and go to the oranges. Now I can't make new witches appear.

```
class Witch(object):
def __init__(self, position, image):

    self.image = image
    self.speed = 5

    self.position = [random.randint(0, 760), random.randint(0, 200)]       
    self.destination = (random.randint(350, 500), random.randint(350, 550))  
    self.play = True 


def draw(self, surface):
    if self.destination != self.position:   
        v = (self.destination[0] - self.position[0], self.destination[1]-self.position[1])
        n = math.sqrt(v[0]**2 + v[1]**2)
        uv = v[0]/n, v[1]/n

        self.position[0] += uv[0]*self.speed
        self.position[1] += uv[1]*self.speed

    if self.destination == self.position:
        self.position = self.position

    surface.blit(self.image, self.position)

class MyGame(object):
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize a new game"""
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
    pygame.init()        

self.oranges = []  
    for x in xrange(25):
        position = self.width//2, self.height//2
        self.oranges.append(Orange(position, self.orange))

    self.witches = []  
    for x in xrange(4):
        position = self.width//2, self.height//2
        self.witches.append(Witch(position, self.witch))

    self.pos = 0, 0
        if self.timer > 30:
        for i in self.oranges:
            i.draw(self.screen)

        if len(self.witches) == 2:
            for witch in self.new_witches:
                self.new_witches.append(witch)
                witch.draw(self.screen)

        for witch in self.witches:
            witch.draw(self.screen)
            witch_x = witch.position[0]
            witch_y = witch.position[1]                



            if int(witch_y) in range(350,550):
                for o in self.oranges:
                    self.oranges.remove(o)
                    if len(self.oranges) == 0:
                        self.lives -= 1    

            player_click_x = witch_x-35 <= self.pos[0] <= witch_x + 35
            player_click_y = witch_y-40 <= self.pos[1] <= witch_x + 40
            if player_click_x == True and player_click_y == True:
                self.witches.remove(witch)
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when it reaches the destination? Go to another random destination? Oscillate between start and destination? Instantly jump back to start then travel to the destination again?

Comment: @Tim I've made mistake in uderstanding what's wrong with my game, now I've updated the description

Comment: So you want the new random witches to appear in the same start position as the old (killed) witches?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid exactly

Answer (score 0):

Witch has to remember start position all time.

```
 self.start_position = self.position = [random.randint(...), random.randint(...)]
```

When Witch dies you move it from `witches` list to `unused_witches` list and change its `position` to `start_position`

```
self.witches.remove(witch)
witch.position = witch.start_position
self.unused_witches.append(witch)
```

than you can use it again later

```
if len(self.witches) <= 2:
    for witch in self.unused_witches:
        self.witches.append(witch)
        self.unused_witches.remove(witch)
```

---

By the way:

You can this

```
if int(witch_y) in range(350,550):
```

write as

```
if 350 <= int(witch_y) < 550 :
```

`range(350,550)` gives list 350...549

You can this

```
witch_x-35 <= self.pos[0] <= witch_x + 35
```

write as

```
-35 <= self.pos[0]-witch_x <= 35
```

or

```
abs(self.pos[0]-witch_x) <= 35
```

Comment: it still doesn't seem to work. And I think you didn't understand me right, I don't need to blit in exactly the same position as another one just in the same rang. Now it appends the witch but it appends it in the same position with remaining two not in the start